# importing sibling file in a module in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

my python project has this directory structure

```
├── main.py
└── util
    ├── color.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── student.py
```

`main.py` is :

```
from util.student import fun
fun("calling fun from main")
```

`color.py` is :

```
def color_fun(a):
    print(a)
```

`student.py` is :

```
from color import color_fun

def fun(var):
    color_fun(var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun("calling fun from student")
```

`__init__.py` is empty

when I try to run `python3 student.py` it works as expected. but when I try to run `python3 main.py` it doesn't work as expected, while it works fine in python2.

I want to run `python3 student.py` as well as `python3 main.py` how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this slight modification in your `student.py`

```
def fun(var):
    color_fun(var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from color import color_fun
    fun("calling fun from student")
else:
    from util.color import color_fun
```

The `PYTHONPATH` for Python3 is causing the problem